# RegEx to find string between occurences of character

Tags: regex, oracle

I have pipe delimited file, something like that:

```
col1|col2|col3||col5|col6||||col10
```

(some columns might be blank as you can see above)

I want to fetch string between 5th and 6th occurrence of pipe. It would be '`col6`' in this example.

How to do that with RegEx?

I wanted to put such file in Oracle db and then do this by using REGEXP_SUBSTR, but I could also do it via different tools (e.g. Notepad++), just need to know RegEx pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern `'(.*?)(\||$)'` to look for any characters (`.*`) in a non-greedy way (`?`) followed by either a pipe symbol - which has to be escaped as `\|` - or (unescaped `|`) the end of the string (`$`). If you don't include end-of-line then it will still work for position 6, but won't find the last element if you need that since `col10` isn't followed by a pipe delimiter.

You would then use that as:

```
select regexp_substr('col1|col2|col3||col5|col6||||col10',
  '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 6, null, 1) as col6
from dual;
```

| COL6 |
| --- |
| col6 |

where the `6` is saying you want the sixth occurrence of the match.

Using a CTE to simplify it a bit, you can see what it extracts all the elements, including the nulls, by changing that occurrence number:

```
-- cte for sample data
with your_table (str) as (
  select 'col1|col2|col3||col5|col6||||col10' from dual
)
  -- actual query
select
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as col1,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 2, null, 1) as col2,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 3, null, 1) as col3,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 4, null, 1) as col4,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 5, null, 1) as col5,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 6, null, 1) as col6,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 7, null, 1) as col7,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 8, null, 1) as col8,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 9, null, 1) as col9,
  regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 10, null, 1) as col10
from your_table;
```

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | col2 | col3 | *null* | col5 | col6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | col10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kj4C2EbU)

This kind of pattern is often used to split delimited strings into multiple rows too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle expert, so there might be better ways but you should be able to work with this expression:

```
(\w*)\|
```

It matches all groups of word characters (`\w`, with the `*` capturing empty groups as well) followed by the pipe (`\|`, escaped since the pipe character has special meaning in regular expressions). Then you can simply extract the 6th group.

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65e02d/1):

```
select
  regexp_substr('col1|col2|col3||col5|col6||||col10', '(\w*)\|', 1, 6, NULL, 1)
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be regex, I'd suggest *oldfashioned* `substr + instr` approach:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'col1|col2|col3||col5|col6||||col10' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '|', 1, 5) + 1,
  4                     instr(col, '|', 1, 6) - instr(col, '|', 1, 5) - 1
  5               ) result
  6  from test;

RESULT
----------
col6

SQL>
```